# Generic type where T is derived from a generic type

Tags: c#

I have an abstract class called `Foo`, which is generic.
And there's a class called `Bar`, which is also generic, but needs `T` to be derived from `Foo`. But I can't do that without specifying a generic type for `Foo`, which I don't want to do - I want *any* class derived from `Foo` to be eligible.

```cs
abstract class Foo<T> { }

class Bar<T> where T : Foo { }
// This gives me CS0305 - Using the generic type Foo<T> requires 1 type argument.
```

I'm sure there's some sort of super obvious solution I'm missing.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: `class Bar<T> : Foo<T> { }` ?

Comment: @Karoshee No. I don't want `Bar` to derive from `Foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

You have two options:

- Create non-generic class `Foo` and make `Foo<T>` implement it (just like `IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable`)
- Make `Bar` use two generics instead of one

  `class Bar<T1,T2> where T1: Foo<T2>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a class that is not generic like the following

```
public abstract class Foo { }
public abstract class Foo<T> : Foo { }
```

And now you can use your constrain with Foo

```
public class Bar<T> where T : Foo { }
```

And this will be required to `T` be a type of `Foo` and as long as you derive generic `Foo<>` from non-generic `Foo` your `T` must be `Foo<T>`

Example of usage:

```
public abstract class Foo { }
public abstract class Foo<T> : Foo { }
public abstract class Boo : Foo<string> { }

public class Bar<T> where T : Foo { }

public class BarTest : Bar<Boo> { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Question` is meant to be `Foo<>` you could use:

```
class Bar<T, T2> where T : Foo<T2> { }
```